# How can I sync data on Android devices via LAN without knowing the IP address of either device?

Tags: android, tcp, udp, synchronization, lan

People using my app should can sync there android-smartphone with other participants in a LAN using my app. All of them have dynamic IP-addresses. If Someone makes changes, it is very importand that everyone get all changes. One of the participans should sync the information with a server in internet (the first one). So it is very important that the otherone get informed if a new one join or anotherone leave the network (If the first one leave anothor one should sync with the internet). How can I build such a network? I already tried jGroups but it has a very high energy-consumption. An other idea is to solve it with IP-multicasting, but than it is not save that everyone get the Datas. Does anybody know how to build such a network? Are there any other tools to use?

Comment: I once used a service discovery library to locate a device on a LAN network from an Android phone. I think it was JmDNS. It sounds like you can do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hybrid udp multicast and tcp process where the udp multicast just says that someone has joined the network. The device should then, on receiving this message, connect to the server via tcp and authenticate. The server would only tell the device of who joined if they are authenticated.